# SOLVED QT deploy hide a string visible in QT build

Tags: c++, reactjs, qt

I've developed a React app encapsulated in a QT app.
I've added some new features on React side and wanted to deploy them on QT.
I've added all new files on resources.qrc and refreshed the old ones, just to be sure.
I build and run the app on QT and everything works perfectly.
I then deploy the app with the simple command:

windeployqt.exe "C:\builtProgramLocation\builtBprogamName.exe"

as usual and always do.

The strange thing is that one (and one only) of the new strings is not visible, all the others yes (even the other strings added with this update).

I've cleaned the build folder and deploy folder and redo all the steps but nothing changed.

What I might miss?

EDIT
Found the solution, it was a CSS rule that was ok for QT builder but not for QT deployer.
I don't know why and it is really strange... but now the text is visible and in the right place.

Comment: Maybe parts of ReactJS-bundle are cached somehow (always ignoring changes).

Comment: I've cleaned resources, build and deploy folders... there should not be any cache this way, at least I think... or am I wrong?

Comment: Qt's web-engine is based on Chromium (previously WebKit); did you clear that's cache?

Comment: Found the solution! It was a CSS rule that was ok for QT builder but not for QT deployer.